# Adding content from a database into a dropdownlist in struts2

Tags: mysql, struts2

I am doing my project in struts2 framework. but i cant find  a way to specify a dropdown list from a database.. is there a way.. pls help

Comment: If this answer meets your requirements accept it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about a drop down list in your JSP page than there is already a [select Tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/select.html.)  for that

```
<s:select name="mydrop_down" list="%{sports}" />
```

where ***list*** is a Iterable source to populate from. If the list is a Map (key, value), the Map key will become the option 'value' parameter and the Map value will become the option body.

All you need to create a `List/Map/Array` in you action class and provide its getter and setter how the list will be picked form the ActionClass in jsp will be handled by the framewrok itself

### Action Class

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSuport{

  private List<String> sports;  //can be array or map etc

   getters and setters for sports

   public String execute() throws Exception{
      sports = init the List and fill it
      // can fill the list from database
      return SUCCESS;

   }
}
```